# Will CommandTimeout property override timeout argument in SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, command-timeout

If I use below c# code to retrieve stored procedure from DB

```
 _command = database.GetStoredProcCommand("ReadQueue");
 _command.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

`ReadQueue` procedure in DB:

```
BEGIN
    EXEC('WAITFOR (RECEIVE * FROM MSGQUEUE), TIMEOUT 120000 ;')
END
```

What will the timeout be when I execute the command from the code, 0 or 120s?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both and neither.

If you'd used command timeout = 100 seconds, it would have timed out after 100 seconds, and never mind the "WAITFOR".

Command timeout is "indefinite" in your example, so the "WAITFOR" kicks in instead.
I'm assuming SQL 2102 here BTW.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx

"TIMEOUT" only applies to Service Broker, so under Receive https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963(v=sql.110).aspx we see:

"If the time-out expires, RECEIVE returns an empty result set."

So after 120 seconds, you'd continue execution with an empty result set (no error occurs) and whatever you have after that point would continue execution normally.